# Can't find crate peg_syntax_ext

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Can't find crate peg_syntax_ext.

This is the beginning of the main.rs:

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(peg_syntax_ext)]
```

What to do?

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to write a [MCVE]. There is an enormous lack of detail in the question, and that led to an answer which did not fully solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `peg-syntax-ext` create to your `Cargo.toml` file, as follows:

```
[dependencies]
peg-syntax-ext = "0.5.2"
```

Comment: OK, but now I've got this:
   Compiling peg-syntax-ext v0.5.2
error[E0554]: #[feature] may not be used on the stable release channel
 --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/peg-syntax-ext-0.5.2/lib.rs:1:1
  |
1 | #![feature(plugin_registrar, quote, rustc_private, box_patterns)]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `peg-syntax-ext`.

Comment: @VladimirTatarchevskiy " #[feature] may not be used on the stable release channel": use the nightly compiler. You could have easily searched for that error message though.

Comment: @VladimirTatarchevskiy It may be good to read up a bit more on using the rust compiler, rust attributes and unstable features, as it seems you're trying to use something without knowing what it does,and that can lead to a lot more complications than just a few questions on StackOverflow.